# Sumproduct Excel one condition two columns to multiply and add

Tags: excel

I am trying to use excel to calculate how much of a number of components from bills of materials (BOMs) are used per month.

So I have several columns of components but a component can appear in several columns. Offset from these columns is the quantity of that component in the BOM and in another column are the sale quantities.  Is SUMPRODUCT the correct formula to use?

I have tried:

```
=sum(sumproduct((B2:B10="Component1")*(L2:L10)*(AH2:AH10)), sumproduct((C2:C10="Component1")*(M2:M10)*(AH2:AH10)))
```

B and C columns contain the component codes, L and M the component quantity per BOM and AH the sales quantity.

What am i doing wrong?  Will this work?  The quantities this returns are not correct.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SUMPRODUCT, you should use comma or semicolon depending on your locale to separate the arrays being multiplied instead of using multiplication operator (*).

```
=SUM(SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$B$10="Component1"),$M$2:$M$10,$AH$2:$AH$10),SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$B$10="Component1"),$L$2:$L$10,$AH$2:$AH$10))
```

Since ($B$2:$B$10="Component1") evaluates to an array of TRUE & FALSE, you use -- to convert that to 1 or 0. You can also multiply it by 1.

```
=SUM(SUMPRODUCT(1*($B$2:$B$10="Component1"),$M$2:$M$10,$AH$2:$AH$10),SUMPRODUCT(1*($B$2:$B$10="Component1"),$L$2:$L$10,$AH$2:$AH$10))
```

Answer (score 0):

SUMPRODUCT treats array entries that are not numeric as if they were zeros.  The first parameter in each of your sumproducts will evaluate to either TRUE or FALSE but they are not strictly numeric.  You can coerce them to numbers - TRUE = 1, FALSE = 0 by:

- Multiplying by double negative
- Multiplying by 1 or
- Adding 0

So change your formula to:

```
=SUM(SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B10="Component1")*(L2:L10)*(AH2:AH10)),
SUMPRODUCT(--(C2:C10="Component1")*(M2:M10)*(AH2:AH10)))
```

Comment: The `--` is only needed if no other math is being done with the boolean expressions,  Just the `*` of the other two is sufficient to turn the boolean inot their bit components.  The `--` are not needed.